# Getting error 255 when compiling with nvcc

Tags: cuda, printf, nvcc

I get the following error when compiling a CUDA kernel with NVCC. I am using Tesla K20C which has compute capability of 3.5. I am using printf inside the kernel for debugging purposes.

> nvcc -c -g -o pagerank.o pagerank.cu -O3 -Xptxas -abi=no -I../moderngpu/include -L../moderngpu -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35
>   ptxas warning : 'option -abi=no' might get deprecated in future
>   ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function 'vprintf'
>   make: *** [pagerank.o] Error 255

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: Did you include stdio.h? What happens if you remove the abi switch?

Comment: The duplicate question/answer includes all of the necessary details to make in-kernel `printf` work.  In your case, note in the comments there that specifying `-Xptxas -abi=no` will certainly prevent your ability to use in-kernel `printf`, and you need to `#include <stdio.h>` (and you need to compile for a proper device architecture, which you are already doing).

Comment: This question is not duplicate because I am using a device with compute capability of 3.5, so the solution given at the other question doesn't solve my problem. Also, I am including stdio.h.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't read your comment completely.